# Class Library Intellisense not showing up after adding the dll to the references

Tags: c#, intellisense, class-library

In C#, I made a ClassLibrary that has one Namespace and one Class.
I saved it and build it.
in other Projects, when i use it, I add it to my references by browsing to the .dll location.

But The Problem is that its name is not showing up in the Intellisense.
i.e when I: `using ...` my dll doesn't show .. 
I'm Importing the library to a ConsoleApp.
both of the App and the library target Framework is .NET Framework 4.0
and I made their Assembly Version 4.0.0.0 so they're the exact same.

is there a setting or something that I'm missing ?
how can i make it pop up ?

I'm using VS2010 Professional

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it a compatible project type and framework version?  That is, are you trying to use a 4.5 DLL in a 2.0 project?  Or compiled a full .NET CLR assembly and tried importing it into a Silverlight project?

Comment: No I Think There's no problem with what you're saying.
I'm just importing it to a ConsoleApp..
And I'm using 4.0

Comment: It could possibly be that your class library was compiled in .NET 4.. however your console app might be running in .NET 4 Client Profile.. check the project settings for both and make sure they are the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm Sure, They're both the same Target Framework

Comment: the namespace has just one class, is it visible (public)?

Comment: Is the namespace for your assembly different than the namespace for your currently open project?  I've had times when the current project _and_ an assembly share the same namespace path the intellisense can mess up.  Also, you stated that the intellisense isn't working for `using`, but does the project build?  Does the intellisense work when accessing _members_ rather than namespaces?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair: Thank You So Much man, you tip was very helpful
it solved the problem, but in fact, the names were different at first (when it wasn't showing up).
after I made them the same, the intellisence worked !
I guess programming is full of hair tearing events :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this be usefull, I was having a similar issue, I have a Web project, add the reference to a Class Library by selecting the project, but if I made a change on the class library, I can´t see that change on the intellisense of the Web Project, after try many things, I see that in the recently added reference, the value of the option "Local Copy" was set "True", then I change it to false and everething works!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but in my case it was a property on the class. If you go to the file properties and look for a **Build Action**. Somehow mine was set to `Content` it had to be set to `Compile`.

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: In my scenario it was set to Compile so I chaged it to Content and rebuilt. I then changed it back to Compile and rebuilt again and it bought back intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Is the namespace for your assembly different than the namespace for your currently open project? I've had times when the current project and an assembly share the same namespace path the intellisense can mess up.

In general, Visual Studio is pretty good about intellisense generation, especially for C#. But sometimes there are some interesting conditions regarding ambiguities, and especially mixing project types where it just doesn't quite work.

Placing your content in the same namespace makes me wonder if you've actually fixed the problem (it may just be autocompleting the namespace in the currently loaded project rather than the assembly), but if it allows you to continue working, then go with it!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project on which you add reference of your dll/project select menu `project dependancies` and `select/MarkCheckBox` for reference project/dll. then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the class library project had its name changed after creation, then intellisense may fail finding it due to directory issues, I believe.

I created my class with the generic "ClassLibrary1" or whatever, and then later changed the default namespace, class name, and project name inside of VS2017. I closed VS2017 and changed the directory name to match my default namespace, and then re-associated the project file in VS2017, and then re-added the reference in my main project file.

All seems to be fixed now.