# Dll reference not working in referenced project

Tags: c#

I have a couple of class library project Businell Logic(Bll.dll built in .Net 4.0 and Targets .Net 4.0) and DataAccess Layer(DAL.dll built in .Net 4.0 and Targets .Net 4.0) that I wish to reuse in another project(a class library project built in .Net 4.6.1).
So I added these two dll's to the dependencies folder of the target project and everything compiled successfully.

But when I try to call any methods in the dll's the intellisense is not working and build errors out saying `Name does not exist in current context`. I tried by changing the Target framework of target project to 4.0 still it doesn't work. 
I am using VS 2017 professional. what am I missing here.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894494/class-library-intellisense-not-showing-up-after-adding-the-dll-to-the-references) thread seemed similar but didn't help

Comment: Did you look on the .csproj file to assure that the reference is well referenced?

Comment: `well referenced`? you mean, correct path to the correct dll? if so, yes the path looks right for the reference

Comment: Sorry for the english. Are you referencing the other project or directly the dll?

Comment: :) No prob.. Yeah I am using the dll..since the methods I want to use are already there in the  project..I thought adding it as a dll is a lighter solution so I can leverage  the methods without having all the heavy lifting code by adding the project to my solution

Comment: Are your classes and methods public in the dll you are referencing? Check your app.config or web.config to make sure the correct version of the framework is being loaded

Comment: There are few private methods in dlls but most of them are public I am not seeing any of them in intellisense. I didn't have any app.config or web.config yet  when  I tried to add app.config I see this line `<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/></startup></configuration>`

Comment: Did you add reference on three project by doing `right click on the project in solution explorer and select add reference`?